# Missing new line in executing diff

Tags: shell

If I use the command `diff <file1> <file2>`, I am getting the result with some warnings; please see below:

```
      diff: Missing newline at the end of file file1
      diff: Missing newline at the end of file file2  
      <param-value>net:12569</param-value>
      <param-value>net:12342</param-value>
```

Please let me know whether the "Missing new line" is a warning or an error.

Comment: It's a warning. It means the last line doesn't end in a line feed.

Comment: So there will be no issue rite? just for confirmation

Comment: @Thangan: POSIX expects that every text-file ends with a newline. Most real-world programs handle a missing newline relatively gracefully, but we cannot promise you that "there will be no issue", because we don't know what-all programs you use, and we don't know what-all things you would consider to be "issues".

Comment: There *could* be an issue, which is what warnings are for. The `diff` on my system doesn't issue a warning, so I suppose it handles no EOL just fine. I tried a little test and it seems to. I'd recommend testing it out on a couple of examples and see if it diff's the last line properly if you're concerned.